# convergence of series, double factorial against power function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

It is known that the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{C^n}{n!}<\infty$$
for any $C>0$, that is, the factorial kills the Power function.

I wonder now if
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{C^n}{n!!}<\infty$$
and in either case how is it proven?

Thank you all! :)

Comment: For the second sum, split it into two sums, one summing over even $n$ and the other over odd $n$. Use the Ratio Test to show both of these, thus your second sum, converge. (The Ratio Test also shows that your first series converges.)

Comment: Exactly, the ratio test Works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use $n!>n^ne^{-n}$ to show that
$$(n!!)^{1/n}>\sqrt{2n/e}$$
for even $n$, and something similar for odd $n$, so $(n!!)^{1/n}\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.  Then use the $n$th root test.

Comment: I think the value of the second series is bigger than the first, I can't compare, can I?

Comment: Ah... could be...  @mark, please clarify.

Comment: Yes, $n!!$ means $n!! = n*(n-2)*(n-4)*...$ (if $n$ is odd then it is the Product of odd numbers, and if $n$ is even, it is the Product of even numbers)

Comment: See revised answer.